# Dynamically Importing Styles in Quasar Project

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm working on a Quasar project and I'd like to dynamically import styles to improve my project's organization. Currently, I'm manually importing numerous stylesheets for components, layouts, and pages, which is becoming unwieldy. Here's an example of what I'm trying to avoid:

```scss
app.scss
@import 'quasar.variables.scss';

// Components
@import 'components/button.scss';
@import 'components/draggable-table.scss';
@import 'components/filter-panel.scss';
...

// Views
@import 'views/auth/login.scss';
@import 'views/auth/recover.scss';
@import 'views/dashboards/dashboards.scss';
...

// Layouts
@import 'layouts/auth.scss';
@import 'layouts/sidebar.scss';
@import 'layouts/navbar.scss';
...
```

In my `quasar.config.js`, I've tried the following:

```js
const { configure } = require('quasar/wrappers');
const path = require('path');

require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = configure(function (/* ctx */) {
  return {
    // ...
    css: ['../../node_modules/flag-icons/css/flag-icons.min.css', 'styles.js'],
    // ...
  };
});
```

My css folder structure for styles is:

```markdown
-css
  - app
    - components
      - styleFiles.scss
      - ...
    - layouts
      - styleFiles.scss
      - ...
    - pages
      - styleFiles.scss
      - ...
  quasar.variables.scss
  styles.js
```

I've tried adapting a similar approach that worked with Vuetify, where I used a `styles.js` file to dynamically import styles, like this:

```js
// Component SCSS Instances
const components = require.context('@/components/.', true, /(.*).scss$/);
const componentStyles = components.keys().map((key) => components(key).default);

// Layout SCSS Instances
const layouts = require.context('@/layouts/.', true, /(.*).scss$/);
const layoutStyles = layouts.keys().map((key) => layouts(key).default);

// Page SCSS Instances
const pages = require.context('@/pages/.', true, /(.*).scss$/);
const pageStyles = pages.keys().map((key) => pages(key).default);

// App SCSS Instances
const apps = require.context('@/css/.', true, /app\/(.*).scss$/);
const appStyles = apps.keys().map((key) => apps(key).default);

// Combine all styles into a single array
const allStyles = [
  ...componentStyles,
  ...layoutStyles,
  ...pageStyles,
  ...appStyles,
];

export default allStyles;
```

However, this approach doesn't seem to be working as expected in the Quasar project. Has anyone successfully tackled this issue before? I'd greatly appreciate any insights or alternative approaches to achieve dynamic style importing in a Quasar project. Thank you!